# Issues on saving to isolatedStorageSettings

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I am saving data(String) to isolated data storage,it was saving data successfully ,but the while retrieve data from data Storage,I a getting data of previous page.
I am having String variable in App.xaml.cs and i assign the values to it from pages,on deactivating the app,information abt last page gets saved and when i restore it ,i should get my saved String,But this is place i am getting this issue,I get some time the previous or before pages values,If i delete the app and build app successfully it works successfully,but when withou deleting the app and when going on doing build and build process,I am getting this issue.

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("endResponse"))
      {
          IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[endResponse] = App.endResponse;
      }
      else
      {
          settings.Add("endResponse", App.endResponse);
      }
```

and for retreiving i am using

```
  if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("endResponse"))
             {
                 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<String>("endResponse", out App.endResponse);

             }
             Debug.WriteLine("App.end Response in IsolatedStorage while activation>>>" + App.endResponse);
```

When deleting the app from simulator and while testing the app,it works well ,apart from it I am not getting exact values always.

I am attaching the screenshot of issue,plz check and tell me ,if i miss anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After writing your settings, you need to call the Save method :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["endResponse"]
```

rather then this in your post?

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[endResponse]
```

Comment: What an silly mistake i made,thanks for info,I am checking it